# Displaying space seperated input in same column

Tags: python, mongodb, tkinter, treeview, pymongo

I am transfering my database to a tkinter window by using ttk.treeview with this code.

```
for row in database.Clients.find({}, {'_id': 0}):
        row
        tree.insert("", END, values=row.values())
```

and here is a snopshot of it. [image]

This view is okay for me but if I add a new customer with address for example "X street" the "X" part is shown under the address column and "street" part is shown under the column next to it. That's not just for address entry. For every entry with space same thing happen. What can I do to show "X Street" entry under the address column?

Comment: Try `tree.insert("", END, values=[x for x in row.values()])`.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is exactly the way I wanted it.